# How do I make this loop work for my palindrome test?

Tags: c, loops, palindrome

I am really new to coding and I need to create a palindrome test that tests numbers up to a given limit. I understand the algorithm to test whether or not a number is a palindrome. However I'm having trouble looping the code. 
The output should look like this: 
if the limit is 1000:

1. limit | # of palindromes | sum of reciprocals
2. 100      18                   3.086147       (1/10 of the limit)
3. 200      28                   3.157490        (2/10 of the limit)

All the way up to the limit given by the user.

I have started the code however my code loops infinitely. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double num;
    int upperLimit = 0; //Limit of the program.
    int numPalindromes = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int tempLim;
    int i = 1;

    printf("Enter the limit of the program:");  //Asks for the limit you want the program to go to
    scanf("%d", &upperLimit);

    // We now need to use an algorithm to test whether or not the number is a palindrome.
    while(num <= upperLimit) {
        int temp;
        int rev = 0;
        temp = num;

        while(temp != 0 ){
            rev = rev * 10;
            rev = rev + temp%10; // we need to add the remainder when the number is divided by 10 to the reverse.
            temp = temp/10;
        }
        /*A number is a palindrome if its reverse is equal to itself. Now we must add its reciprocal to the sum and increase the amount of palindromes by 1 if the number is a palindrome */
        if(num == rev) {
            sum = sum + (1/num);
            numPalindromes = numPalindromes + 1;
        }

        while (num <= upperLimit) {
            tempLim = upperLimit * (i/10);
            if (num == tempLim) {
                printf(" %d %d %lf\n", tempLim, numPalindromes, sum);
            }
            i++;
        }
        num++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the value of an object with automatic storage duration before it is initialized is undefined behavior.

Comment: The first time you refer to `num` it has an undefined value `while(num <= upperLimit)`. Prob not the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have such a snippet:

```
while (num <= upperLimit) {
    tempLim = upperLimit * (i/10);
    if (num == tempLim) {
        printf(" %d %d %lf\n", tempLim, numPalindromes, sum);
    }
    i++;
}
```

However, neither `num` nor `upperLimit` is modified inside the loop. Thus it loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (num <= upperLimit) {
        tempLim = upperLimit * (i/10);
        if (num == tempLim) {
            printf(" %d %d %lf\n", tempLim, numPalindromes, sum);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

num is not changing, upperlimit is not changing. So it runs infinitely.

Comment: The loop does have `num++` but first time use is unitialised.

Comment: I put num++ at the end to make it run through the algorithm again to test if the number is a palindrome and then go back through the loop to print.

Comment: `num++` is inside the first `while` loop but not in the nested one posted here.

Comment: @zach1198, what is that you are trying to accomplish in this loop inside?

Comment: @JayKumarR I was trying to have it increase the number up until it hit a fraction of the limit and then have it increase the fraction of the limit until it reaches the limit (not sure if that made sense). I managed to get this to work with if and else-if statements.